# javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find public key for catpcha

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, captcha

I want to implement captcha in my application, but i get this error can anybody tell me reason ??

> juin 01, 2014 12:22:04 PM com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback visit
>   GRAVE: javax.faces.FacesException: Cannot find public key for catpcha, use primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY context-param to define one

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See the message, you need to register for a CAPTCHA key then add the following to your web.xml

```
   <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PUBLIC_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>your-publickey</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.PRIVATE_CAPTCHA_KEY</param-name>
        <param-value>your-private-key</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

To register goto : https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html