# Unknow Host Exception while using Primefaces Captcha

Tags: java, primefaces, captcha, weblogic12c

While using tag 'P:Captcha' in Prime Face 6, Weblogic 12c i am facing following exception.

```
<Feb 21, 2018 4:20:30 PM PKT> <Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101019> <[ServletContext@24665149[app:_auto_generated_ear_ module:/ path:null spec-version:3.0]] Servlet failed with an IOException
java.net.UnknownHostException: www.google.com
   at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
   at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
   at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
   at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
   at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:625)
```

We are behind proxy internet. Also i have added following scripts in setDomainEnv.cmd

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% %JAVA_PROPERTIES% -Dhttp.proxySet=true -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.1.10.2 -Dhttp.proxyPort=80 -DUseSunHttpHandler=true
```

can any body please help me.

Comment: Please let me look at your class code, where exception occurs

Comment: i have just added this tag in my xhtml file.
<p:captcha id="captcha" label="Captcha" secure="true"/>

Comment: PrimeFaces uses Google reCaptcha. Have you got Google reCaptcha keys?

Comment: If you haven't try to look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23979342/javax-faces-facesexception-cannot-find-public-key-for-catpcha

Comment: yes i have already added captcha key as defined in the link.

Comment: the main issue was due to proxy internet the captcha was unable to connect to google server. As reCaptcha v2 has https link, therefore by adding following code in setDomainEnv.cmd captcha is now working fine.
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dhttps.proxyHost=172.18.101.2 -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts="127.*|localhost"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was proxy internet. The Captcha was unable to connect to google server due to proxy. As reCaptcha v2 has https link, therefore by adding following code in setDomainEnv.cmd captcha is now working fine.

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=%JAVA_OPTIONS% -Dhttps.proxyHost=172.18.101.2 -Dhttps.proxyPort=80 -Dhttps.nonProxyHosts="127.*|localhost"
```